# Array field contains array values of other field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Sample data:

```js
db={
  "Test": [
    {
      "x": [1, 2],
      "y": [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      "x": [1, 2],
      "y": [2, 3, 4]
    }
  ]
}
```

To match static array values I can do this:

```js
db.Test.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "y": {
        "$all": [1, 2]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

..to get the desired result where all values of `x` is in `y`:

```js
[
  {
    "x": [1, 2],
    "y": [1, 2, 3]
  }
]
```

But I need to find arrays that have values of an array field. Tried using `$all` with `$expr` but that is not allowed:

```js
db.Test.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$all": [
          "$x",
          "$y"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

What can I do instead? Thanks.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/omONVXwiCky)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can treat your arrays as sets with unique items, you can use the [`$setIsSubset`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) operator for this, e.g.:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        "$setIsSubset": [
          "$x",
          "$y"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

The operator returns `true` if the first array is a subset of set second one. For your sample, this returns the first document, but not the second.

See this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3-WdXOvYv8a) to test.

Comment: Ah, missed that family of set operators, thanks!